# C++ When to use which (standard) exception?

Tags: c++, exception

The header `<stdexcept>` defines a couple of standard exceptions. However, I have troubles determining when to use which exception. Are there good guidelines to be found on-line? I try to illustrate my problem with an example:

A function takes the length of a (physical) vector and an angle (between 0 and pi) to return a new vector. If the angle is negative is that

1. A `std::invalid_argument`, as negative angles are invalid?
2. A `std::logic_error`, as negative angles do not make sense in this case?
3. A `std::out_of_range`, as negative angles are outside the allowed range for angles?
4. A `std::domain_error`, as the mathematical function is not defined on negative angles.
5. Or should I define a custom exception?

(In case anybody wonders: I am trying to transform coordinates in a triclinic simulation box, which are actually three lengths and three angles - see [here](http://lammps.sandia.gov/doc/Section_howto.html#howto-12) if you are interested.)

Comment: This is entirely up to you. No matter what exceptions are thrown, unless they're caught they'll abort the problem. So, whatever exception you decide you're going to throw, you're going to catch somewhere. So, it's entirely up to you.

Comment: You might want to introduce your own exception types to distinguish your errors from standard ones.

Comment: Ok, I have to figure out my own guidelines then. Are there more detailed descriptions for which cases the standard exceptions were initialliy intended. The descriptions on both [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/stdexcept) and [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/) are extremely brief.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The intentions for these exceptions:

[`std::invalid_argument`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/invalid_argument):

> Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It reports errors that arise because an argument value has not been accepted.

[`std::logic_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error):

> Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It reports errors that are a consequence of faulty logic within the program such as violating logical preconditions or class invariants and may be preventable.
>
> No standard library components throw this exception directly, but the exception types `std::invalid_argument`, `std::domain_error`, `std::length_error`, `std::out_of_range`, `std::future_error`, and `std::experimental::bad_optional_access` are derived from `std::logic_error`.

[`std::out_of_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/out_of_range):

> Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It reports errors that are consequence of attempt to access elements out of defined range.

[`std::domain_error`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/domain_error):

> Defines a type of object to be thrown as exception. It may be used by the implementation to report domain errors, that is, situations where the inputs are outside of the domain on which an operation is defined.

---

Given that, I would rule out use of `std::logic_error` and `std::out_of_range` for your situation.

`std::ivalid_argument` is less specific than `std::domain_error`. Hence, my recommendation would be to use `std::domain_error`.

Comment: This answer does not clarify anything besides what the documentation says. Which is, I believe, the reason for the question. Besides your opinion, the answer does not clarify why one would favor one type over other since all of them seem to be the same in the context of this question 's example